# Is it feasible to write query to find data from a table which has two different columns with same data in different order

Tags: sql, arrays, ms-access

I have a table in which two columns have same data in different rows. 
I have table for inventory where I have three columns. First column is Serial No, Second column is Model and third column is part of. First column and third column have same kind of data.

```
Serial No   Model           part of

1234        Optiplex 745    
1235        Optiplex 755    
6565        Optiplex 620    
6566        Optiplex 270    
9877        Optiplex 755    1235
9876        Optiplex 745    1234
1236        Optiplex 745
```

I want to display results like below, which shows rows associated with serial no # 1234 and row associated with Part of #1234

```
Serial No   Model           part of

1234        Optiplex 745    
9876        Optiplex 745    1234

1235        Optiplex 755    
9877        Optiplex 755    1235
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting and elaborate a little more please?  Add commas between columns.  Since your headers and data don't align, it's hard to tell what data comes from what column.  I can't follow what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to retrive data by model  where i can combine results for same serial no and same part of No.

Comment: So your columns are `Serial No` and `Model` and `Part Of`?  In your results, what columns are you showing?  It looks like just `Serial No` and `Model` but not `Part Of` on the first row, but on the second row it looks like you're including a `Part Of`.  Or is `Part Of` null in those cases?  Again, commas would go a long way.

Comment: Data for Part of Column is null in some of the rows. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Are you purposely leaving the row with Serial No 1236 out of the results for Model Optiplex 745?  If so, why?  Is it because it doesn't have any subparts?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT [Serial No], Model, [part of]
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Serial No]=1234 Or [part of]=1234
```

Edit re comment

```
SELECT [Serial No], Model, [part of]
FROM BulkBR
WHERE [Serial No] IN (SELECT [part of] FROM BulkBR)
   OR [part of] Is Not Null
ORDER BY Model, [part of]
```

Comment: Query you mentioned just pulled for serial No/part of 1234, however i do not want to specify particular serial No/Part Of, I would like to have all rows in results which can satisfies both conditions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Select * from Inventory Where [Serial No] Like (Select PartOf from Inventory) OR [Part Of] like (Select SerialNo from Inventory) - I tried this query , did not work.

Comment: I think I understand, how about the second example?

Comment: I want results in sequance like first row :1234,Optiplex 745  Second Row: 9876,Optiplex 745,1234

Comment: Olivier Jacot's solution looks great, only thing  i need result  in group by model.

Comment: What do you mean in group by model?

Comment: Thank you Forester93, Eli, Remou for input, you guys are so kind and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT
    Nz([part of], [Serial No]) AS [associated to],
    [Serial No],
    Model,
    [part of]
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    Nz([part of], [Serial No]),
    [Serial No]
```

The result will be

```
associated to   Serial No   Model           part of

1234            1234        Optiplex 745    
1234            9876        Optiplex 745    1234

1235            1235        Optiplex 755    
1235            9877        Optiplex 755    1235

1236            1236        Optiplex 745
6565            6565        Optiplex 620
6566            6566        Optiplex 270
```

The additional row `[associated to]` will help you to group the results in a report, for instance.

Comment: your query runs like champ, is it possible to group by [associated to] column in result of query.

Comment: Thank you Olivier for all your big help.

Comment: A GROUP BY statement requires an aggregate function like SUM, MAX, or AVERAGE. This is not useful here. You can use group headers and footers reports in order to group records visually. Another possibility is to use a pivot query (crosstab query in Access) which transforms rows into columns. The disadvantage is that you get a variable number of columns with variable names (e.g. by transforming serial numbers into column names). This makes it very difficult to use such a query for a report; however, it can be useful to just show the query result directly to the user.